# Hausdorff property with initial topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Consider a topological space $X$ such that the topology on $X$ is the initial topology with respect to the family of maps $f_i:X \to Y_i$ where $Y_i$ are Hausdorff. Show that $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if for every distinct $x,y \in X$ there exists $i$ such that $f_i(x) \ne f_i(y)$. Here $i$ belongs to an arbitary indexing set $I$.

First I'll try the converse direction. Assume that for distinct $x,y \in X$ there exists $i$ such that $f_i(x) \ne f_i(y)$. Then since $Y_i$ is Hausdorff we can take neighborhoods $U$ of $f_i(x)$ and $V$ of $f_i(y)$ such that $U \cap V= \emptyset$. Now as $f_i$ is continuous we have that $f_i^{-1}(U)$ and $f_i^{-1}(V)$ are open. But $\emptyset = f_i^{-1}(U \cap V)=f_i^{-1}(U) \cap f_i^{-1}(V)$ and $x \in f_i^{-1}(U), y \in f_i^{-1}(V)$. So for all $i$ we have distinct neighborhoods for $x,y$ which makes $X$ Hausdorff.

Now assume that $X$ is Hausdorff and that there exists $i \in I$ for which $f_i(x) = f_i(y)$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff take $U$ open set containing $x$ and $V$ open set containing $y$. Then $U \cap V = \emptyset$. Because $X$ has the initial topology $x \in \bigcap_{i \in A} f_i^{-1}(U_j) \subset U $ and $y \in \bigcap_{i \in B} f_i^{-1}(V_j) \subset V$ for $A,B \subset I$ finite.

Let $G$ be an open set containing $f_i(x) = f_i(y)$, then $f_i^{-1}(G)$ is open in $X$ and $x,y \in f_i^{-1}(G)$. Will this imply that $$x \in \bigcap_{i \in B} f_i^{-1}(V_j) \subset V$$ and $$y \in \bigcap_{i \in A} f_i^{-1}(U_j) \subset U $$contradicting the Hausdorff property of $X$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y$ and: $$f_i(x)=f_i(y)\text{ for every }i\in I\tag1$$

Let $\tau\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ such that it contains exactly the subsets $U$ of $X$ that satisfy:$$x,y\in U\text{ or }x,y\notin U$$
Then $\tau$ is evidently a topology and if $X$ is equipped with this topology then for every $i\in I$ function $f_i$ is continuous. This because $(1)$ implies that preimages of the functions $f_i$ are open.

That means that topology $\tau$ is finer than the topology that is initial wrt the $f_i$.

But $(X,\tau)$ is not Hausdorff (there are no disjoint open sets $U,V$ with $x\in U$ and $y\in V$) allowing us to conclude that also the coarser topology on $X$ initialized by the $f_i$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: Nice trick. I've learned something new.

Comment: @Mateo It is also nice to hear that.